# Xcode swift managing multiple view controllers in multiple storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a big project. and in future it will have multiple view controllers in each storyboard.

is there any way to remember which view controller in which storyboard.

Can any buddy help me

Comment: Write down on a chart and paste it on your desk.

Comment: Don't put multiple view controllers in each storyboard file. Firstly it will make them a lot slower to load when you open one, and secondly it's bad organisation. Instead use a separate storyboard for each view controller and then name the storyboard file the same as your view controller file. This way you will always know which storyboard belongs to each view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Please add this extension in your code

```
extension String {
     func viewController (_ vc: String) -> UIViewController? {
         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: self, bundle: nil)
         let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vc)
         return vc
    }
}
```

//Please add function in viewController with class name and storyboard name

```
class MYViewVC: UIViewController {
    static func viewController() -> MYViewVC {
        return "Authentication".viewController("MYViewVC") as! SelectLanguageVC
    }
}
```

//Please use this code When you push

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {

    let vc = MYViewVC.viewController()
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
}
```